# Change Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Dynamic Table that changes based on the value of B1.
I want the value of B1 to change by clicking on another cell from another workbook. I'm super new to VBA and don't really know what I'm doing.

What I want is to click on any cell from column E and it will change the value of B1 to equal value of column O.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Dynamic Table").Range("B1").Value = ActiveCell.Offest(0, 10)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[My Amateur Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouri9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean sth like that

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            Worksheets("Dynamic Table").Range("B1").Value = Target.Offset(, 10).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I assumed you mean with another workbook just another worksheet.

Comment: sorry to be a pain. got another question. what if i wanted to add another code so when i click on column F. cell value of C1 in the worksheet "Dynamic Table" turns into value of column p?

Comment: Just add another if condition similar to the one above. If you get stuck please create another post and refer to this one.